# Reset cursor's position to the beginng each time the script is being launched

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I'm currently studying `T-SQL` procedures and cursors, but I've faced the problem recently. How can I reset to the beginnig position of the cursor that was returned from the procedure (after fetching all the data from it)? I have a cursor in the following context:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.my_procedure
    @curs CURSOR VARYING OUTPUT
AS
    SET @curs = CURSOR
    SCROLL FOR
        select book_name, author_lastname
        from dbo.books;
OPEN @curs;
go

declare @tmp_curs cursor;
declare @val_1 varchar(35), @val_2 varchar(35);


EXEC dbo.my_procedure @tmp_curs output;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    print @val_1 + ' ' + @val_2 + ';'
    FETCH NEXT FROM @tmp_curs
    INTO @val_1, @val_2;
END;
CLOSE @tmp_curs;
DEALLOCATE @tmp_curs;
go
```

When I run this script for the first time I get the result I need (entries from the cursor). But when I run this next time I only get result as

> "(100 row(s) affected)"

And not the actual entries, so I have to restart Server Management Studio.

I have tried working with
`@@FETCH_STATUS`,
reexecuting procedure, and
closing-opening cursors but nothing seems to work for me. How can I get the same result (entries from cursor) each time I run this script?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can use `FETCH FIRST FROM`:

```
DECLARE @tmp_curs cursor;
DECLARE @val_1 varchar(35), @val_2 varchar(35);

-- first run
EXEC dbo.my_procedure @tmp_curs output;
FETCH FIRST FROM @tmp_curs INTO @val_1, @val_2;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO books2 VALUES (@val_1, @val_2);
    FETCH NEXT FROM @tmp_curs
    INTO @val_1, @val_2; 
END;
CLOSE @tmp_curs;
DEALLOCATE @tmp_curs;

-- second run
EXEC dbo.my_procedure @tmp_curs output;
FETCH FIRST FROM @tmp_curs INTO @val_1, @val_2;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO books2 VALUES (@val_1, @val_2);
    FETCH NEXT FROM @tmp_curs
    INTO @val_1, @val_2;
END;
CLOSE @tmp_curs;
DEALLOCATE @tmp_curs;

-- checking
SELECT *
FROM books2;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7125b0/5/0)**</kbd>

Comment: @RandomGuy Does it help or not?